# Getting experimental data ready for presentation

Tags: plotting, fitting

I would like to create a plot for my diploma, but I am having several issues when I attempt to do so.

1. I want to get an approximated plot of two consequences of
   point (temperature and ration of current factor). If I evaluate something like

   ```
   ListPlot[Transpose[{time, ration}], Joined -> True, Axes-> True]
   ```

   I get a curve, but it is not as smooth as I would like it to be.
2. Do You know a method to get the parameters of a function from a sets of points? For example, I know that my function is expected to be `const1(1-Exp[-const2*t)]`, How can I get the constants?
3. How can I plot a theoretical function on the same plot as the experimental dats?

Comment: Many of the commands shown by executing `?*Fit` should help, such as `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`.  Look them up in the documentation, which also shows how to plot them

Comment: what you are after is probably a fit, not interpolation, see `NonlinearModelFit`

Comment: I changed the code for your model to `const1(1-Exp[-const2*t)]`.  In case you didn't know, built-in functions begin with a capital, including standard math functions, and function arguments are wrapped in brackets `[ ]`, not parentheses `( )`.

Comment: After you find the fit with [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), you can combine the plots with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html?q=Show).

Comment: I strongly urge you learn more from the documentation before asking such general question here. I recommend starting with the two documentation articles [Curve Fitting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CurveFitting.html) and [Create Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreatePlots.html)

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what type of data you have. To overcome this issue, I generated some data from your 'expected function'.

Let us first define your expected function in MMA without the arbitrary constants

```
f[t_] := (1 - Exp[-t])
```

Now generate a data table which will contain `{t,f(t)}`

```
data = Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Your expected model is

```
model = a*(1 - Exp[-b*t]);
```

where we need to find `a` and `b`.

To fit the data to the expected model, we can use one of the two `NonlinearModelFit` or `FindFit` as suggested repeatedly in the comments

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b}, t,Method -> NMinimize];
```

or

```
FF = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, t, Method -> NMinimize];
```

Now to know the arbitrary constants `a` and `b`,

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {a -> 1., b -> 1.}

or

```
FF
```

> {a -> 1., b -> 1.}

Now plotting `data` vs `fit`

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Red, PointSize[0.03]}], 
 Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

Finally, you can plot the `data` and the theoretical function combine like this

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Red, PointSize[0.03]}], 
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 10}]]
```

**Edit**

The OP has provided some data in two different lists.

```
currentfn = {1.004144, 1.458798, 1.579908, 1.974147, 2.045930}
time = {114, 171, 228, 365, 502}
```

Now we need to combine the two lists to make acceptable for `NonlinearModelFit`

```
newdata = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {time, currentfn}]
```

Finally, fitting the data

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[newdata, model, {a, b}, t, Method -> NMinimize];

nlm // Normal

Show[ListPlot[newdata, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Red, PointSize[0.03]}], 
 Plot[nlm[t], {t, 114, 502}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @AlexandrBolotnikov If you share your data then maybe you will get some help, otherwise it is a guessing game?

Comment: 1)thank You MMM for ur detailed answer
2) my data is 2 list like that 
currentfn = {1.004144, 1.458798, 1.579908, 1.974147, 2.045930}
time = {114, 171, 228, 365, 502}
3)And when I tried to use NonlinearModelFit function with parameters

Comment: with that command NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{time, currentfn}], 
 a*(1 - E^(-bx)), {a, b}, x]

Comment: I got the next error Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted. >>

Comment: I didn't realise what does in mean and what should I do to avoid that error but a tried to change a data type corresponding the type in Mathematika's documentation and have changed the data type

Comment: data = {{1.004144, 114}, {1.458798, 171}, {1.579908, 228}, {1.974147, 
   365}, {2.045930, 502}}
nlm =  NonlinearModelFit[data, a*(1 - E^(-bx)), {a, b}, x]

Comment: and the matematika displayed error again

Comment: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is \
nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted. >>

Comment: @AlexandrBolotnikov I have Edited the answer.

Comment: @AlexandrBolotnikov you should edit the question to add additional info.

Comment: @MMM his model is `model = a*(1 - Exp[- b t])`  (Fits much better that way!)

Comment: @george2079 Thank you for pointing that out. I will correct this mistake.